# Asterisk interpretation by shell

Tags: command-line, bash

I know that `*` supposed to be interpreted by the shell not by the command being invoked

Now if I run the following command in my home directory

```
$echo *
```

I get

```
Desktop Documents Pictures Downloads  ...etc
```

But if I ran the command in an empty directory I get

```
*
```

as output

Why is that? why `echo` print `*` while `*` is not escaped and only interpreted by the shell

Shouldn't the output be blank line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [answer](https://superuser.com/a/901192/749566) gives a possible explanation.

I will quote from it :

> note that if the expansion leads to nothing, i.e. in that case if the directory contains no non-hidden files, the * is left unchanged and passed as is to the command called.

That is, it expands the wildcard character *, but when it matches nothing, it is retained as is and passed to the command called, 'echo' in this case.

Comment: ... unless the shell's `nullglob` or `failglob` option is set

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a source for the same.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html